# Success function in ajax when using setInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

Well I would like to check answer from server every 5 seconds. But my success function inside $.ajax just does not work. Although ajax sends requests and gets response. Time limit is not exceeded since function is run every 5 seconds and response is received within 1 second.
If i put something inside checkMyCreatedGame function after $.ajax it does work but success function does not.

```
var checkMyGame;
checkMyGame =setInterval(checkMyCreatedGame,5000);
var checkMyCreatedGame = function(){
    $.ajax({
            url   :'../cgi-bin/lobby.py',
            type  :"GET",
            cache :false,
            data {
                "checkMyGameId":createdGameId,
                "player":playerName
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(jsonData){
                console.log(jsonData)

            }
    });
};
```

Here is my firebug console logs when I run this code (do not pay attention to what is above those gets):
[image: firebug]

Here is same screenshot but not resized by stackoverflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9HBa.png
As you can see console.log inside success function is not executed.

Comment: Because you're telling jQuery to expect JSON and then sending plain text?

Comment: @lonesomeday: No, `dataType:"json"` is what you expect from server, not what you send to the server. I think the code on server side has error and `success` is not called. If he provides an `error` function, this function may be called.

Comment: Editing your code, I noticed that you have syntax errors, like missing a `:` in the data option etc.

Comment: @KhanhTO Exactly: the server sends a success response ("200 OK") with content that isn't JSON when the jQuery is expecting JSON.

Comment: @lonesomeday: maybe I got you wrong, I thought "sending plain text" is from browser.

Comment: Yeah, the problems was that I was sending plain text instead of JSON. Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AJAX call, you tell jQuery to expect JSON data:

```
dataType:"json",
```

Then your server returns non-JSON data:

```
waiting
```

jQuery then tries to parse it as JSON, and unsurprisingly, fails. If you tell jQuery to expect text instead, it will work fine:

```
dataType:"text",
```

The message of this is: if you are finding that an AJAX call is failing silently, put an `error` handler in. If you had, you would have received a message telling you that you had a `parsererror`.

Comment: Thank you! It was the case.